# the KeyError: 1 problem , whats the problem?

Tags: python, django

in this code :

```
j=1
for item in orderOFsssReserve:
  fforderOFsssReservefff=[]
  for item0 in orderDoubles1:
    if(item.studentidof== item0.userid):
      orders_student[j].setdefault(j, []).append(item0)
      break
```

in this line of code  :

```
      orders_student[j].setdefault(j, []).append(item0)
```

I have this error :

```
KeyError: 1
```

help me please

Comment: You're using the variable `j` in your code, where did you define that? The error signals that you are trying to retrieve an element from a dictionary using the key '1', which is not available in your dictionary. I suspect that is caused by you using the `j` variable in your code.

Comment: Obviously, there is no key `1` in `orders_student`. Post your input values.

Comment: i defined the `j =1` variable befor this code .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my problem was:

> orders_student[j].setdefault(j, []).append(item0)

and i try this :

> orders_student.setdefault(j, []).append(item0)

it works !